# How to alter order for subpartition in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have created a table with subpartitions based on month and I accidentally make the December become the first month. So now it looks like this in `information_schema.partitions`:

[image]

Here is the code that I created the partition:

```
ALTER TABLE table123
 PARTITION BY RANGE( YEAR(CreatedDate) )
    SUBPARTITION BY HASH(MONTH(CreatedDate) ) (


        PARTITION p2016 VALUES LESS THAN (2017) (
            SUBPARTITION dec_2016,
            SUBPARTITION jan_2016,
            SUBPARTITION feb_2016,
            SUBPARTITION mar_2016,
            SUBPARTITION apr_2016,
            SUBPARTITION may_2016,
            SUBPARTITION jun_2016,
            SUBPARTITION jul_2016,
            SUBPARTITION aug_2016,
            SUBPARTITION sep_2016,
            SUBPARTITION oct_2016,
            SUBPARTITION nov_2016
        ),

        PARTITION p2017 VALUES LESS THAN (2018) (
            SUBPARTITION dec_2017,
            SUBPARTITION jan_2017,
            SUBPARTITION feb_2017,
            SUBPARTITION mar_2017,
            SUBPARTITION apr_2017,
            SUBPARTITION may_2017,
            SUBPARTITION jun_2017,
            SUBPARTITION jul_2017,
            SUBPARTITION aug_2017,
            SUBPARTITION sep_2017,
            SUBPARTITION oct_2017,
            SUBPARTITION nov_2017
        )

        PARTITION p2018 VALUES LESS THAN (2019) (
            SUBPARTITION dec_2018,
            SUBPARTITION jan_2018,
            SUBPARTITION feb_2018,
            SUBPARTITION mar_2018,
            SUBPARTITION apr_2018,
            SUBPARTITION may_2018,
            SUBPARTITION jun_2018,
            SUBPARTITION jul_2018,
            SUBPARTITION aug_2018,
            SUBPARTITION sep_2018,
            SUBPARTITION oct_2018,
            SUBPARTITION nov_2018
        )
```

I wonder if there is any way to modify the order of the subpartitions without recreating or dropping the subpartitions and not effecting the data sitting in the table?

Comment: That order is the usual way to do it (and no accident). And no, you cannot change the subpartitions anymore. Why would you want to change them anyway?

Comment: @Solarflare i need to set up an automate task to drop old subpartitions and it's going to be better if I have a normal order...

Comment: If it's better to have them in normal order, you have to recreate your partitions, you cannot modify your subpartitions anymore. Btw, you cannot drop hash subpartitions, just truncate them.

Comment: @Solarflare thx. I know i can't drop the subpartitions, my solution is to exchange the subpartition to another table and drop that new table. I am not sure if I can truncate the subpartition. Could you please advise? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can truncate subpartitions (with mysql >= 5.7.2).